# Looking wepage trought localhost

Tags: webserver, localhost, web-design

I want to look my webpage saved on my computer but some js and ajax stuf doen't work, because it's not on server or something. I understand, that you are suposed to use localhost somehow. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

All the web servers have something called a document root. A location on the filesystem which they treat as the root of the website '/' and all the paths are relative to that unless explicitly modified by configuration changes or by the application code.

If you are using a web framework like Django, it doesn't serve the static files like CSS and JavaScript files when you deploy it in production but works just fine in the development server. So you will have to copy the static files to a location from where your web server can serve it and reference those files using that path.

If you are using Apache 2, the default document root is at /var/www